# Curl works for YTB website but gets blocked for GitHub

Tags: windows, curl, proxy

"Why is it that when I use curl on a YTB website URL in PowerShell, it connects successfully, but when I use curl on GitHub, it goes into a blocked state? After a blue bar flashes, there is no response, and even typing on the keyboard doesn't do anything."

I am using Windows 10 on my computer and using Clash for proxy purposes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXr73.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4nJ4.png)

"I want to download a package manager called Scoop, but Scoop cannot access GitHub. Additionally, I'm curious about this ambiguous issue."

Comment: That's quite absurd. I just looked up what the ping command is. I tried using the ping command.
I can ping GitHub successfully, but curl doesn't work.
I can curl YTB successfully, but ping doesn't work.